# AngularJS activate Semantic UI component without jQuery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, semantic-ui

I'm creating a site with `AngularJS` and `Semantic UI`.

It's all fine with `CSS` components but I'm facing a problem: To active `JavaScript` components, there's no way.

For example, I can activate a component by

```
$('.ui.modal').modal('show');
```

This is `jQuery` styled code. Now I'm in `AngularJS` with no `jQuery`. How can you deal with that problem?

How can I activate a component with a `jQuery`-free way?

(I checked that `GitHub` issues and repo, there's no answer.)

If I have to, can I import a minimum file just for the `Semantic UI` requirements?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [`ngShow`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) and [`ngHide`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide)?  This may be what your controller looks like:

```
angular.module('MyApp').controller('ModalCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.show = false;

    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.show = true;
    }, 5000);
});
```

While the HTML may look like:

```
<div ng-controller='ModalCtrl'>
    <div class='ui modal' ng-show='show'>
        <!-- Modal Contents -->
    </div>
</div>
```

This code will hide the element with the `ngShow` attribute for 5 seconds.  After 5 seconds, the modal will appear.  If you want to add animations you can do so using [`$animate`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations).

The best place to find out what you can and cannot do with Angular natively is to look at the [list of directives Angular provides](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive).  If you can't find what you are looking for you have 2 options: [make your own directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) or search the Internet for the appropriate directive (there are many, many directives for Angular already).  In general, try avoiding jQuery and prefer "the Angular way" TM.

Comment: Thanks, But `ng-show`, `ng-hide` seems doesn't work. Is it need to be initialized by `$('.ui.modal').modal()`?

Comment: I need a little more code than what's provided to help.  [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [CodePen](http://codepen.io/) would be nice.